# Finding converge diverge in sequence

Tags: calculus

I am wondering if I found the correct limit on the following sequences.

$\frac{n^2}{n+1}$

dividing by $n^2$ I got

$\frac{1}{1/n+1/n^2}$

which then I get 0.

another one is

$2\ln(3n)-\ln(n^2+1)$

I did

$2\ln(\frac{3n}{n^2+1})$

I got 2ln(0)

My final one is

$\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+n}}{n}$

$\frac{\sqrt{4n^2/n+n/n}}{n/n}$

Then I got 1

Comment: The first one is wrong, also the second one ($\;\log(0)\;$ isn't defined), and also the last one...

Comment: On the first one, before doing algebra, it is useful to *look*. For big $n$, the number $n^2$ is much bigger than $n$ (or $n+1$), so $\frac{n^2}{n+1}$ will be big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac{n^2}{n+1}\ge\frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac n2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\;??$$

$$2\log(3n)-\log(n^2+1)=\log(9n^2)-\log(n^2+1)=\log\frac{9n^2}{n^2+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\;??$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+n}}{n}==\frac{n\sqrt{4+\frac1n}}n=\sqrt{4+\frac1n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\;??$$

Comment: Well the first one I think is dne

Comment: I don't understand what you meant to say, @FernandoMartinez

Comment: The first limit  one is does not exist because it keep growing.

Comment: The second one I think the limit is 9/2

Comment: Well, the first one's limit is infinite: it does exist but not finitely (sometimes one says the sequence *diverges*) . The second one's limit is $\;\log 9=3\log3\;$

Comment: yes that makes sense hmm it seems the last one would  be 2 as the limit

Comment: Así es, @FernandoMartinez

Comment: One thing I do not get is in a sequence is there any way to tell when you factor out an n and when you should divide by n

Comment: Practice and more practice, "@FernandoMartinez .